# Center two divs next to each other at the bottom of a parent div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I try to achieve the effect that on my blue screen two controls are centered on the bottom, next to each other... I tried to center them using:

```
.volumeControl{
    float: right;
    background: red;
}
.muteButton{
    background: green;
    float: right;
}
```

and it almost worked, but first of all - the elements are not in the center of the screen, and second of all - somehow the mute button is on the left side (and I would like to put it on the right side of the volume bar)..
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/en0r1Lgu/

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the separate divs and put the slider and button inside the main controls div. Use spans instead of divs http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/8u506jy6/

Comment: Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharkhatiwada/en0r1Lgu/4/

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When centering it's adviseable not to use floats. `display:inline-block` with `text-align:center` on the parent works much better.

```css
#video-controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 223px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.volumeControl {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.muteButton {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#volume-bar {
  width: 120px;
}
.player {
  position: absolute;
  width: 226px; /* sizes changed for demo reasons only */
  height: 126px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div id="video-controls">
    <div class="volumeControl">
      <input type="range" id="volume-bar" class="volumeRange" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="muteButton">
      <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `margin:auto` instead of floating things

```css
#video-controls{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 223px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.volumeControl{
    margin: auto; /* added */
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;    
}
.muteButton{
    background: green;
    margin: auto; /* added */
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
#volume-bar {
    width: 120px;
}
.player{
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 29px;
    width: 226px;
    height: 426px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
    <div id="video-controls">
        <div class="muteButton">
            <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button> 
        </div>
        <div class="volumeControl">
            <input type="range" id="volume-bar" class="volumeRange" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" />
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `dispplay:inline-block` insteed of `float` then remove the habitual undesirable space between inline-block elements with a small negative margin and don't forget to use `vertical-align`property to set the elements the right way:

```
.volumeControl{
display:inline-block;
background: red;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.muteButton{
background: green;
display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:center;
    margin-left:-2px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/en0r1Lgu/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use so much code. This can be easily accomplished with [**CSS Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="player">
        <div id="video-controls">
            <div class="volumeControl">
                <input type="range" id="volume-bar" class="volumeRange" 
                      min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" />
            </div>
            <div class="muteButton">
                <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button> 
            </div>
        </div><!-- end #video-controls -->
    </div><!-- end .player -->
</div><!-- end #container -->
```

CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.player {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 226px;
    height: 426px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#video-controls {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.volumeControl { background: red; }
.muteButton { background: green; }
#volume-bar { width: 120px; }
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/en0r1Lgu/7/)**

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).*